# Render Only Child Component Only On Prop Change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to re-render my child component **without** re-rendering the parent  component when the **parent's state changes**.

In this example, componentWillReceiveProps is never called.

Thank You!

---

**Parent Component**

```
export default class Parent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            myValue: 'hello'
        }
    }

    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
        return false;
    }

    myFunction() {
        this.setState(prevState => {
          return {myValue: 'world'};
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Button onPress={myFunction} title="Learn More"/>
                <Child myText={this.state.myValue}/>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

**Child Component**

```
export default class Child extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        console.log('This Is Never Called');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>{this.props.myText}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the reasoning for that?

Comment: Trying to prevent unnecessary flickering when component is rendered.

Comment: There won't be flickering if you're doing everything properly, the framework takes care of this. I'd expect the code you posted to work ok with component re-rendering. It's like the existing answer says, parent component should be re-rendered in order to re-render a child, and this is the way it's usually done. Any way, I posted an alternative just FYI. If you have real problems with flickering on rerenders, this is likely XY problem, I'd suggest to ask a new question and address the problem with flickering directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to re-render child component with new props, parent component has to be re-rendered. There are generally no reasons to not re-render parent component in this situation. React was designed to do this efficiently and reuse existing DOM elements on re-render where possible.

The alternative approach is to make child component re-render its children and make parent component trigger the update somehow.  This can be done with refs, for instance:

```
export default class Parent extends Component {
    state = {
        myValue: 'hello'
    }

    childRef = React.createRef();

    myFunction = () => {
        this.childRef.current.setText('world');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Button onPress={this.myFunction} title="Learn More"/>
                <Child ref={this.childRef} myText={this.state.myValue}/>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

And child component maintains its own state:

```
export default class Child extends Component {
    static getDerivedStateFromProps({ myText }, state) {
      return {myText, ...state};
    }

    setText(myText) {
      this.setState({ myText });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>{this.state.myText}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-x1pg7a).

This is acceptable solution but it results in less straightforward design. 'Dumb' `Child` like in original code is a preferable way to do this which shouldn't be changed for optimization reasons in general. If there are problems with re-rendering `Parent` children, they possibly should be addressed in another way.

Comment: I can't see the `childRef` anywhere :) Probably on the `p` in the `Child` right? Also, I can't make `setText` work. Could it be `this.childRef.current.textContent = "world";`? Oh, by the way I'm not the OP :)

Comment: @devserkan Thanks for noticing, yes, I've missed `ref` prop. Updated the answer with a demo. It could be so but doing it this way and using `this.textContent` in child render would also require to do `this.childRef.current.forceUpdate()` to make it re-render, this smells badly.

Comment: This means that I understood the whole point wrong :) I think I need to study the refs a little bit more. Since I passed the ref with a custom name then used in the `p` tag. Then when `setText` did not work I thought the `textContent` way. I can't find any documentation about `setText`, can you point me in the right direction, please? Without setting our ref in the Child's any element how can we set a text there? How did it target the `p` element (or `text` in your example) includes `myText`?

Comment: Lol, I think I need to sleep :D `setText` is the Child's method here, how couldn't I see this. Sorry for bothering :)

Comment: @devserkan Sure, no problems.

Comment: I have a use case to update child & not parent. Consider whatsapp chat list. It shows chat name and last chat message in one line. On redux change for new message, you have to update that last chat message line but not chat name.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to do what you are proposing explicitly. When you define:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    return false;
}
```

are telling `Parent` never to rerender after its initial render. However the passing of props to `Child` (and therefore the impetus for `Child` to rerender) happens inside the `render` method of `Parent`. So when you block rerending on `Parent` you are also blocking rerendering on all children of `Parent`.

There is, however, no need to block rerendering on `Parent` because React will modify the DOM as little as possible, so you will only see changes in parts of parent that need to be modified (due to a change of state). As long as all the props being passed to the other children of `Parent` (other than `Child` that is) remain unchanged, only `Child` will be modified in a `Parent.render` call.

Basically React already handles what you are trying to do.